# Clarification on a paper regarding estimating N from a Binomial Distribution

Tags: bayesian, estimation, binomial-distribution, posterior

I was wondering if someone could clarify the following for me.  In the paper ["Inference for the binomial $N$ parameter"](http://pluto.huji.ac.il/~galelidan/52558/Material/Raftery.pdf) by Adrian Raftery, his first example outlines the posterior of $N$ given $x$ as

$$
p(N|x) \propto (N!)^{-1}\left\{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\binom{N}{x_i}\right\}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\theta^{-N+S}(1-\theta)^{nN-S}\lambda^N\text{exp}(-\lambda/\theta)p(\lambda,\theta)d\lambda d\theta
$$

He assumes a Poisson distribution as the prior distribution for $N$, so I understand where the

$$
(N!)^{-1}\lambda^N\exp\left(\lambda/\theta\right)
$$

comes from.  However, why is the exponent of $e$ $\lambda/\theta$?  Thanks!

Comment: What are $\lambda$ and $\theta$?

Comment: Related:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123367/estimating-parameters-for-a-binomial/123748#123748

Comment: In the paper the author assumes a Poisson prior distribution for N with mean $\mu$.  The author says then that marginally, each $x_i$ has a Poisson distribution with a mean $\lambda = \mu\theta$.  The author decides to specify the prior distribution in terms of $(\lambda, \theta)$.  So I'm assuming that $\lambda = \mu\theta$ and $\theta$ is the success probability.  Hope this helps.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Poisson distribution for $N$ with mean $\mu$ has density
$$
(N!)^{-1} \mu^N \exp(-\mu)
$$
Since $\mu = \lambda/\theta$, this explains the exponent.