# MLE for parameter n in Binomial

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

How is the MLE for n calculated if p and k are given? I've been stuck on this forever and cannot seem to even find a similar example of calculating MLE of n.

[image][image]

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123367/estimating-parameters-for-a-binomial/123748#123748

Comment: You can avoid votes to 'close' a textbook question by showing what you have tried and why you need help. Also, a 'self-study' tag seems appropriate. Perhaps 'take the tour' of our site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $k = 25$ and $p = 1/19,$ so the method-of-moments estimator (MME) is 
$k/p = 475.$ We don't know whether the maximum likelihood estimator
is the same, but it may be similar. I will do a grid search in R, where a binomial PDF is denoted `dbinom`,
to find the MLE.

```
p = 1/19;  k = 25;  n = 200:800
like = dbinom(k, n, p)
mle = n[like==max(like)];  mle
[1] 474
plot(n, like, type = "l")
 abline(v = mle, col="red")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Check for uniqueness (because R rounds to some number of places):

```
like[n==474]
[1] 0.08170127
like[n==475]
[1] 0.08170127
```

So the MLE is either 474 or 475. We might as well use the MME.
I will leave it to you to provide an analytic argument that
this answer is correct. (For discrete quantities, a common approach to find a maximum is to look at ratios.)

Of course, all of this assumes that the usual rules of probability apply to extraordinarily beautiful Eastern European princesses playing roulette at the Bellagio.