# Regression of proportions

Tags: regression, binary-data

I have to regress the mortality rate which is in number of deaths per thousand and percentage of vaccinated people. Have sample data for different districts. Can I use linear regression directly. The sample sizes are different for different districts. Please suggest the appropriate method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Analyze proportions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24187/analyze-proportions)

Comment: You'd need to account for other things that affect overall mortality rate, like differences in age distribution. You'd also need to account for differences in variance between these observations, which are due to more than just variation in sample size.

Comment: So the idea is that mortality rate would be your response variable, & % vaccinated would be a covariate, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis would be improved if you had populations for each of the districts. The variance of the rates will depend on the counts, so the standard deviation of each of the rates will be proportional to the standard deviation of the underlying counts. If you had that information it would be reasonably simple to do a Poisson regression. Linear regression could be examined as well but with variance that is different than the usual naive assumptions.

The other issue to consider is whether the relationship is a simple straight line on either the linear scale or on the log scale. Poisson regression is estimating the relationship on the log scale, while linear regression would be doing so in the linear scale. The assumption of linearity on either (or both) of the scales may be incorrect and you should be prepared to do some spline fits to examine the potential for non-linearity with either method.